# js сохранять текст в буфер обмена при переходе на страницу с другим доменов

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Мне нужно копировать текст при переходе на другой сайт с другим доменом, я пробовал использовать это
navigator.clipboard.writeText(
`Страница: ${page} \nБраузер: ${browserState} \nРазрешение: ${resolution}`
);
но это не работает, при переходе на другой сайт, у меня есть модальное окно, там две кнопки перейти в jira и закрыть, мне нужно чтобы, когда я нажимаю перейти в джиру, происходило бы копирование текста и в новой вкладке с другим доменов можно было бы вставить текст из буфера обмена, сейчас получилось лишь делать следующее, при открытии модалки текст сразу копируется в буфер и тогда на другом сайте я могу вставить этот текст, но это не по заданию, по заданию я должен копировать текст лишь при перехеоде по ссылке, я предполагал, что код копирования нужно поместить в обработчик события нажатия на кнопку "перейти в джиру", но это не срабатывает, видимо потому что я перехожу на другой домен или просто потому что в этот момент происходит переход на др страницу, я также пробовал использовать локалсторадж и куки - не работает, и куки и ls сохраняются и видны лишь на странице где сохранял, а на новой странице их нет, подскажите есть ли вариант сделать это, может session storage работает по другому, хотя я сомневаюсь. Да пишу все это на нексте, но без сср, то есть на реакте по сути)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(`${router.asPath}`);
    setResolution(`${screenWidth} X ${screenHeight}`);
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(
      `Страница: ${page} \nБраузер: ${browserState} \nРазрешение: ${resolution}`
    );
  }, [
  ]);

  const handleLinkClick = () => {
    setShowSaveMessage(true);
  };
```

Comment: Если переход на другую страницу – обычная ссылка, то preventDefault(), потом работа с буфером и window.open(). Это ванильный, что в реакте, к сожалению, не в курсе.

Comment: сделал как ты говоришь, но копирования не происходит

Comment: const handleLinkClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    navigator.clipboard.writeText(
      `Страница: ${page} \nБраузер: ${browserState} \nРазрешение: ${resolution}`
    );
    setShowSaveMessage(true);
    window.open(
      'ссылка на сайт с другим доменом'
    );
  };

Answer (score 0):

В местном редакторе не отрабатывает работа с буфером, но я перепроверил на локальных файлах, код работает (проверял Хромом):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", magic);
}

function magic(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText("Some info");
  window.open("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430510", "_self");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <script src="1.js"></script>
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a id="link" href="https://google.com">google.com</a>
</body>

</html>
```